# Change values inside array based on logic - Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an array (called 'img') that I want to modify.

```
img
array([[[244, 244, 244],
    [248, 248, 248],
    [249, 249, 249],
```

I want to change the values in the array to 0 if they are below 200 and convert to 255 if they are above or equal to 200:

```
for value in img:
    if value < 200:
         value = 0
    else:
         value = 255
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I get this code to work?

Comment: You are currently iterating through the img variable, which is a two dimensional list. So `value` is a list as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using Numpy `where` method. Pass Logic as first argument, if True (second argument), if False (third argument).

```
img = np.where(img<200.0, 0.0, 255.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [boolean array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) in [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
np.where(img<200, 0, 255)
```

For the example you provided all values are above 200 so it will return 255 all the time but for 245:

```
np.where(img<245, 0, 255)
Out[4]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]])
```